# While running a simple HelloWorld.java I am getting this internal error : Internal error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError): org.jdom.Attribute.<init>

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

```java
Internal error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError): org.jdom.Attribute.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jdom/AttributeType;Lorg/jdom/Namespace;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jdom.Attribute.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jdom/AttributeType;Lorg/jdom/Namespace;)V
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.SafeJdomFactory$BaseSafeJdomFactory.attribute(SafeJdomFactory.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.SafeStAXStreamBuilder.processElement(SafeStAXStreamBuilder.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.SafeStAXStreamBuilder.processElementFragment(SafeStAXStreamBuilder.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.SafeStAXStreamBuilder.build(SafeStAXStreamBuilder.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadUsingStaX(JDOMUtil.java:285)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.load(JDOMUtil.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.tryLoadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadComponentData(JpsLoaderBase.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadComponents(JpsLoaderBase.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadGlobalComponents(JpsGlobalLoader.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadPathVariables(JpsGlobalLoader.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadGlobalSettings(JpsGlobalLoader.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[image]

Comment: Try re-installing IntelliJ

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Doe the clean installation from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder: I did the same download from your given link. still the issue not resolved

Comment: Please share a sample project and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the JAVA_HOME variable for the user that you are using on your computer? If not, search on youtube how to set JAVA_HOME with java8

Comment: Yes I set the Java_Home variable properly. Even my Eclipse is running good!